# Choosing ctypes dll loading mechanism

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, loadlibrary

I´m working on some code that can access some dll funcionality using ctypes. The library loading was done with:

```
U2_C_INTERFACE = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("mydllname")
```

And this was working in the original developer Windows 10 machine (and others). But on my own machine I got this error when calling library methods:

```
Procedure called with not enough arguments (24 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention
```

After googling I could fix it changing the dll loading method to:

```
U2_C_INTERFACE = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("mydllname")
```

This works in my own Windows 10 machine (and others). But it doesn´t work in the original Windows 10 machine, we get this other error when calling library methods:

```
Procedure probably called with too many arguments (24 bytes in excess)
```

Is there a way to know programatically when to use `cdll.LoadLibrary` and when `windll.LoadLibrary`?

This is the troublesome code, the call to `o_session` is throwing the commented exception

```
if U2_C_INTERFACE is None:
    # U2_C_INTERFACE = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("uvic32")
    U2_C_INTERFACE = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("uvic32")

subkey  = c_char_p(bytes(0))
status  = c_long(0)
host_l  = bytes(servidor_uv,    servidor_universe.devolver_sistema_codificacion())
user_l  = bytes(usuario_uv,     servidor_universe.devolver_sistema_codificacion())
pass_l  = bytes(password_uv,    servidor_universe.devolver_sistema_codificacion())
acc_l   = bytes(cuenta_uv,      servidor_universe.devolver_sistema_codificacion())

# Gestión de apertura de sesión
o_session = U2_C_INTERFACE.ic_universe_session

o_session.argtypes = (
    c_char_p, c_char_p, c_char_p,
    c_char_p, c_char_p, _ctypes.POINTER(c_long))
res = o_session(
    c_char_p(host_l), c_char_p(user_l), c_char_p(pass_l),
    c_char_p(acc_l), subkey, _ctypes.byref(status))
```

The Python version we're using is 3.4.0 (32 bits)

```
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:24:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

My ctypes version is 1.1.0.

Comment: There's no difference in the 64-bit Windows x64 ABI. It only matters in 32-bit Windows x86 ABI, in which `CDLL` is the cdecl calling convention (the caller cleans the stack) and  `WinDLL` is the stdcall calling convention (the callee cleans the stack).  A library can use either calling convention or even mix conventions. You need the function prototypes from the header file that was distributed with the DLL in order to determine the correct calling convention.

Comment: Please post the code that actually throws the error (your'e saying that it's the **same** code that behaves differently on the 2 machines). What are your *Python* versions on the 2 machines? Also what are the *ctypes* versions? `ctypes.__version__`?

Comment: FYI, `ctypes.CDLL` and `ctypes.WinDLL` are generally better than `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary` and `ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary` because instantiating the classes directly allows setting the options `mode` (POSIX `dlopen`), `use_errno` (C), and `use_last_error` (Windows).

Comment: @eryksun we have to stick to the 32 bit version. The problem is that the same method is failing on two different machines.

Comment: @CristiFati I added the code and some additional data.

Comment: Are you positive it's the same *.dll* on both machines? How does your function header look like (the *.h* file)?

Comment: Definitely verify that both systems are using the same version and build of "uvic32.dll". Also, according to [this document](https://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKBnew20/u2%20clients%20and%20apis/v5.1.0/u2clients_intercalldevguide_v510.pdf), the call should be `ic_universe_session(server_name, user_name, password, account, status, subkey)` with `status` as the second-to-last parameter, but it's still 6 pointers (24 bytes) and the same issue with the calling convention. The document says the included header is named "intcall.h" and that the convention should be `PASCAL` (stdcall).

Comment: @CristiFati yes, it´s the same dll, I just copy-pasted the project folder (it´s just two .py files and that .dll file). 
I don´t have the header files, just the dll :/ but I´ll try to find them.

Comment: Use the fully-qualified path to "uvic32.dll" to ensure you're not possibly picking up a different version in the DLL search path.